# Where does symfony2 determine the zapp/config` path?

Tags: symfony, config

I was looking through the code base of symfony and could not see where it defines the convention of looking in the kernel_dir's /config directory.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out. It's set in your AppKernel::registerContainerConfiguration() of course!